# "Pretty Simple Content Slider" with Validate Plugin problems.

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, slider, jquery-validate

So I'm using this jquery content slider plugin: [slider](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/04/28/pretty-simple-content-slider-with-jquery-and-css3/). And I'm also using the jquery validator plugin. So the I have a tab on the content slider to change your password. The problem is the validator's messages aren't appearing when you don't type in things correctly. Here's the jquery for the content slider:

```
$(function() {
    var current = 1;

    var iterate     = function(){
        var i = parseInt(current+1);
        var lis = $('#rotmenu').children('li').size();
        if(i>lis) i = 1;
        display($('#rotmenu li:nth-child('+i+')'));
    }
    display($('#rotmenu li:first'));
    var slidetime = setInterval(iterate,90000);

    $('#rotmenu li').bind('click',function(e){
        clearTimeout(slidetime);
        display($(this));
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    function display(elem){
        var $this   = elem;
        var repeat  = false;
        if(current == parseInt($this.index() + 1))
            repeat = true;

        if(!repeat)
            $this.parent().find('li:nth-child('+current+') a').stop(true,true).animate({'marginRight':'-20px'},300,function(){
                $(this).animate({'opacity':'0.7'},700);
            });

        current = parseInt($this.index() + 1);

        var elem = $('a',$this);

            elem.stop(true,true).animate({'marginRight':'0px','opacity':'1.0'},300);

        var info_elem = elem.next();
        $('#rot1 .heading').animate({'left':'-420px'}, 500,'easeOutCirc',function(){
            $('h1',$(this)).html(info_elem.find('.info_heading').html());
            $(this).animate({'left':'0px'},400,'easeInOutQuad');
        });

        $('#rot1 .description').animate({'bottom':'-270px'},500,'easeOutCirc',function(){
            $('p',$(this)).html(info_elem.find('.info_description').html());
            $(this).animate({'bottom':'0px'},400,'easeInOutQuad');
        })
        $('#rot1').prepend(
        $('<img/>',{
            style   :   'opacity:0',
            className : 'bg'
        }).load(
        function(){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},600);
            $('#rot1 img:first').next().animate({'opacity':'0'},700,function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }
    ).attr('src','Images/'+info_elem.find('.info_image').html()).attr('width','800').attr('height','300')
    );
    }
});
```

And the html for the content slider

```
<div id="content">
    <a class="back" href=""></a>

    <div class="rotator">
        <ul id="rotmenu">
            <li>
                <a href="rot2">Password</a>
                <div style="display:none;">
                    <div class="info_image">2.jpg</div>
                    <div class="info_heading"></div>
                    <div class="info_description">
                        <form id="change_Pass" action="" method="post">
                            Current Password<span style="color:red;">*</span><input type="password" id="change_password" name="change_password"><br>
                            New Password<span style="color:red;">*</span><input type="password" id="new_password" name="new_password"><br>
                            Verify Password<span style="color:red;">*</span><input type="password" id="verify_password" name="verify_password"><br>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="rot1">
            <img src="" width="800" height="300" class="bg" alt=""/>
            <div class="heading">
                <!--<h1></h1>-->
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <p></p>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now here's the jquery for the validator:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("passw", function(value, element) { 
    return this.optional(element) || /^(?=.*[\W])(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/.test(value);
}, jQuery.format("Please enter a valid password"));

$("#change_Pass").validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    errorClass: "req_mess",
    rules: {
        change_password: {
            required: true,
        },
        new_password: {
            required: true,
            passw: true,
        },
        verify_password: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: "#new_password",
        }
    },
    messages: {
        change_password: {
            required: "Please enter your current password",
        },
        new_password: {
            required: "Please enter a new password",
        },
        verify_password: {
            required: "Please enter a password that is a minimum of 8 characters and containers 1 upper case, 1 symbol, and 1 number",
            equalTo: "Your passwords did not match",
        }
    }
});
```

The validator works for other forms no problem so i'm thinking it's the way this content slider is displaying information with this `$('p',$(this)).html(...)` is probably messing with the validator's messages. Or not, I really don't have any idea. I just know when you don't enter in a password that follow the regex, than it doesn't display the error message. I know the regex for the password works because it validates just fine on other forms. So any ideas on what's wrong and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: You have six [_"trailing commas of death"_](http://hirtopolis.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/jslint-and-the-trailing-comma-of-death/).  I realize this is only a problem with IE, but maybe you'd like to know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an easier/better fix.

After this line:

```
$('p',$(this)).html(info_elem.find('.info_description').html());
```

Add this line of code which sets up the validation on the form that was just added to the slider in the previous line:

```
setupPasswordValidate('#rot1 .description #changePass');
```

So you'll also need to put your validate code into a function like this:

```
function setupPasswordValidate(selector)
  $(element).validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    errorClass: "req_mess",
    rules: {
        change_password: {
            required: true
        },
        new_password: {
            required: true,
            passw: true
        },
        verify_password: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: selector + " #new_password"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        change_password: {
            required: "Please enter your current password"
        },
        new_password: {
            required: "Please enter a new password"
        },
        verify_password: {
            required: "Please enter a password that is a minimum of 8 characters and containers 1 upper case, 1 symbol, and 1 number",
            equalTo: "Your passwords did not match"
        }
    }
  });
}
```

The form validation needs to be set up each time `html()` is used to copy the form content. Getting the content with `html()` doesn't copy the events and these are needed to do the validation on the form.

Comment: for some reason, the verify_password input always displays `Your passwords did not match` even if the passwords do match. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I might. See how the verify_password rule matches #new_password? This will likely be fixed if you change `equalTo: element + "#new_password"`

Comment: It breaks DOM rules that #change_Pass and #new_password are essentially duplicated when your form is copied but validate doesn't seem to complain so long as you specify selectors that uniquely identify your form and inputs.

Comment: now the verify never shows anything, as if it always equalts. Maybe it should be `equalTo: "#new_password" + element`?

Comment: Nevermind, `equalTo: element + "#new_password"` is totally wrong. That's what I get for not testing and trying to answer from the hip.

Comment: yah i got this error from the console: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]#new_password`. Maybe define a custom function like i did for passw?

Comment: Ok, it needs a selector so this works: `equalTo: "#rot1 .description #new_password"` ... just give me a minute to rewrite my answer.

Comment: There. I changed the setupPasswordValidate function to use CSS selectors instead of passing in a jQuery object. Now validate can find the specific input it needs to do the validation. Let me know how that works.

Comment: do you mean this line: `equalTo: "#new_password",`?

Comment: Yes but I changed the code in my answer. `equalTo: "#rot1 .description #new_password"` will work though instead of `equalTo: "#new_password"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Replace this line:

```
$('p',$(this)).html(info_elem.find('.info_description').html());
```

With these:

```
$('p',$(this)).html();
var elements = info_elem.find('.info_description').detach();
$('p',$(this)).append(elements);
```

Your form has the validation options defined and event handlers are applied via the validation plugin. The problem is when your code copies only the HTML (as text) of your form. Using detach() removes the actual dom nodes and appends these (complete with validation events) to your slider.

Note: I tried this first using clone(true) instead of detach but it didn't seem to copy the validation properly.

Edit:
One problem with this is the detached form will get lost when the next iteration happens unless it's put back. A simple fix for this is to store the form (the elements var) in a global variable and append it back where it came from before the next iteration.

Comment: so for the problem solution are you saying I should do `var val= $("#change_Pass").validate`? If so, then what do I do with that?

Comment: @Richard No, that's not what I'm saying.